# python3 multiprocessing example crashed my pc :(

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am new to multiprocessing

I have run example code for two 'highly recommended' multiprocessing examples given in response to other stackoverflow multiprocessing questions. Here is an example of one (which i dare not run again!)

**test2.py** (running from pydev)

```
import multiprocessing

class MyFancyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_something(self):
        proc_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        print(proc_name, self.name)


def worker(q):
    obj = q.get()
    obj.do_something()



queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
p.start()

queue.put(MyFancyClass('Fancy Dan'))

# Wait for the worker to finish
queue.close()
queue.join_thread()
p.join()
```

When I run this my computer slows down imminently. It gets incrementally slower. After some time I managed to get into the task manager only to see MANY MANY python.exe under the processes tab. after trying to end process on some, my mouse stopped moving. It was the second time i was forced to reboot.

I am too scared to attempt a third example...

running - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 870 @ 2.93GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.9GHz on win7 64


If anyone know what the issue is and can provide a VERY SIMPLE example of multiprocessing (send a string too a multiprocess, alter it and send it back for printing) I would be very grateful.

Comment: Like a good old fork bomb :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb

Comment: I really like that question. Might be just Schadenfreude though :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html#windows):

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python
>   interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a
>   new process).

Thus, on Windows, you must wrap your code inside a

```
if __name__=='__main__':
```

block.

---

For example, this sends a string to the worker process, the string is reversed and the result is printed by the main process:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(inq,outq):
    obj = inq.get()
    obj = obj[::-1]
    outq.put(obj)

if __name__=='__main__':
    inq = mp.Queue()
    outq = mp.Queue()

    p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(inq,outq))
    p.start()

    inq.put('Fancy Dan')

    # Wait for the worker to finish
    p.join()
    result = outq.get()
    print(result)
```

Comment: Yes i will admit i took that bit out. I had no idea it was so important. thanks. I will accept this answer. If you have time to answer another question ... the do_something(self): has a print statement in it ... but nothing is returned when I run the script, why?

Comment: Have you tried running Ethan Furman's fixed up version of your code? It should print `('Process-1', 'Fancy Dan')`.

Comment: Hm, I don't know why that should be. In the [doc's Windows section](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) there is a very simple 7-line example with printing from the subprocess. Does that example work for you?

Comment: @Rhys: I've been StackOverflowing too much!  I had the back-quotes around `__main__` instead of single quotes -- fixed, and it does print now.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the way `multiprocessing` works on Windows (child processes import the `__main__` module) the `__main__` module cannot actually run anything when imported -- any code that should execute when run directly must be protected by the `if __name__ == '__main__'` idiom.  Your corrected code:

```
import multiprocessing

class MyFancyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_something(self):
        proc_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        print(proc_name, self.name)


def worker(q):
    obj = q.get()
    obj.do_something()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
    p.start()

    queue.put(MyFancyClass('Fancy Dan'))

    # Wait for the worker to finish
    queue.close()
    queue.join_thread()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest [this link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/27/python-threads-communication-and-stopping/)? It's using threads, instead of multiprocessing, but many of the principles are the same.

Comment: thanks, I was already using threads but it proved quite ineffective at increasing process speed. which is why im looking into multiprocessing